# How to read a file, and write it to a different file

Tags: ocaml

I hope all is well. At this point, I plan on reading a file, and then writing it to another file. (The equivalent of `cp` in OCaml, before I go ahead and manipulate text.) Currently in my code, I am making using the [extlib](https://github.com/ygrek/ocaml-extlib) to read a file, and then output it. I am also using `dune` to build file as an executable file. My file looks something like the following:

```
(* example.ml file *) 
let read_filename = "example_1.ts"
let filename = "example_2.ts"

let () =

  let text read_filename =
    let chan = open_in read_filename in
    Std.input_list chan  

  let filename = filename in 
  let text = text in 
  Std.output_file ~filename ~text 
  (* normal exit: all channels are flushed and closed *)
```

When I build the file using `dune build example.bc` I receive the following error:

```
File "example.ml", line 11, characters 2-5:
Error: Syntax error
```

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, but to no avail. Any help would be more than appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have readed you code I remark these lines.

```
  let filename = filename in 
  let text = text in
```

Why have you writting this line ? (* You could delete it safely *)

And then I have found your syntax error was a line above you have forgotten a `in`

```
(* example.ml file *) 
let read_filename = "example_1.ts"
let filename = "example_2.ts"

let () =
  let text read_filename =
    let chan = open_in read_filename in
    Std.input_list chan
  in
    Std.output_file ~filename ~text 
  (* normal exit: all channels are flushed and closed *)
```

The rule for each local definition you must have a `in` keyword
(* a local definition is a let inside a let expression *)

Comment: Note: This will still error out in the compiler, but it is heading towards the right direction, and helps for what I am trying to achieve.